# Can condensation occur in a unsaturated vapor?

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider that a gas mixture of vapor$+$inert gas is unsaturated with concentration (or molar fraction) $x_\infty$ far from a clear, cooled substrate of temperature $T_\text{w}$, i.e. $T_\text{w}<T_\infty$.

Assuming:
(1) Total pressure of the system is constant, say $p_0$;

(2) The saturated concentration $x_\text{w}$, corresponding to $T_\text{w}$ and $p_0$, is less than the far field concentration $x_\infty$, corresponding to $T_\infty$ and $p_0$.

I am confusing whether or not the vapor can condense on the substrate to some extent? or if I have omitted some important factors? Intuitively, I guess that condensation could occur for a while then an equilibrium is obtained at the interface. But I am not sure and would really appreciate if someone can give me some hints. Thank you!

Comment: Is $x_w$ the *bulk* saturation concentration?

Comment: Hi @ lemon, actually, $x_w$ is a reference concentration at wall temperature $T_w$ and bulk pressure $p_0$. It can be regarded as an imaging "wall concentration".

Comment: The criterion for condensation is that the **partial pressure** of the condensing substance must be equal to the equilibrium vapor pressure at the indicated temperature, not the total pressure.

Comment: @ Chester Miller, thank you for your explanation. Is my following understanding correct? Condensation will occur if the partial
pressure of condensable species is larger than the saturation vapor pressure. Moreover, the saturation vapor pressure is actually the saturation partial pressure of condensable species at the given temperature in gas mixture?

Comment: Yes, that is all correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I can see there is a temperature distribution from far field to the wall. For each temperature, the vapor pressure will be different. With lower temperature, the vapor pressure is higher. This means unsaturated gas in far field can be sub-cooled when it approaches the wall due to vapor pressure increasing.

Comment: @ user115350, thank you. I think you fully understand my question. Temperature increases to the substrate. Is the vapor pressure actually the partial pressure of condensable species? Thus condensation could occur at the gas-liquid interface initially according to your explanation. As it thickens, interface temperature increases, and interfacial saturation pressure will be higher. Thus condensation will stop later. Am I right?

Comment: When the condensation continues, the concentration reduces so does the partial pressure. Then condensation will stop unless the far field keeps diffusing the material.